# Number of derangements s0 $4≤f(1)$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm guessing  it's $D_n - 2$ when $D_n = n!\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$

Am I right?

Comment: Depends on the $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $D_n$ the number of derangements of the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. You know an expression for $D_n$.

For any $i$ and $j$, where $i\ne 1$, $j\ne 1$, the number of derangements $f$ such that $f(1)=i$ is the same as the number of derangements such that $f(1)=j$, namely $\frac{D_n}{n-1}$. This is clear by symmetry.

Assume that $n\ge 4$. We want to avoid $f(1)=2$ and $f(1)=3$. The number of derangements that do that is $\frac{n-3}{n-1}D_n$. You can rewrite this as $D_n-\frac{2}{n-1}D_n$.